# How to configure Dependency Ingection with Guice instead of static method at utility class?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, static, guice

I want to get rid of `static` stuff from utility class:

```
public final class PropertiesUtils {

    public static Properties loadProperties(String propFilePath) throws IOException { 
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propFilePath)) {
            properties.load(in);
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

I am using it at one place:

```
public class HiveJdbcClient {
    public HiveJdbcClient() {
        initHiveCredentials();
    }

    private void initHiveCredentials() {
        try {
            Properties prop = PropertiesUtils.loadProperties(FileLocations.HIVE_CONFIG_PROPERTIES.getFileLocation());
```

I have already implemented some `GuiceModulel`:

```
public class GuiceModel extends AbstractModule {    
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(XpathEvaluator.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(HiveJdbcClient.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(QueryConstructor.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

***I couldn't catch how to get rid of static stuff with Guice at this method?***

I want to have next signature;

> public Properties loadProperties(String propFilePath)

instead of:

> public static Properties loadProperties(String propFilePath)

Comment: Um... make `PropertiesUtils` into `PropertiesLoader` and make the method non-`static`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following lines to your code:

To your module (before actually binding the providers):

```
Map<String, String> bindMap = Maps.newHashMap(Maps.fromProperties(properties));
bindMap.putAll(Maps.fromProperties(System.getProperties()));

Names.bindProperties(binder(), bindMap);
```

In your provider:

```
@Inject
@Named("hive.password")
protected String password;

@Inject
@Named("hive.uri")
protected String uri;
```

You will need in the one or other way to load the properties, but this way, you do not need to know the file name of the properties file within your client. Everything is managed at the DI level.

Comment: What do you call `model` here and `provider`? can you explain much detailed?

Comment: Module = GuiceModel  extends AbstractModule and provider = HiveJdbcClient

Answer (score 1):

Just add `PropertiesUtils` binding to `GuiceModel` like:

```
bind(PropertiesUtils.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

PropertiesUtils.class

```
public class PropertiesUtils {

public Properties loadProperties(String propFilePath) throws IOException { 
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propFilePath)) {
        properties.load(in);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

HiveClient.class << Inject PropertiesUtils

```
public class HiveJdbcClient {
private final PropertiesUtils props;

@Inject
public HiveJdbcClient(PropertiesUtils props) {
    this.props = props;
    initHiveCredentials();
}

private void initHiveCredentials() {
    try {
        Properties prop = props.loadProperties(FileLocations.HIVE_CONFIG_PROPERTIES.getFileLocation());
```